# Parse both symbols . and , as decimal digits delimiter in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server-2008, parsing, delimiter

I'm writing a banking system and my customer wants support both Russian and American numeric standards in decimal digits delimiter. Respectively `.` and `,`.

Now only `,` works properly. Perhaps because of web server's OS format (Russian is set).

String like `2000.00` throws a `FormatException`:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

How to fix that? I have next two ideas:

```
protected void FormView1_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
   var txtAmount = (TextBox)((FormView)sender).FindControl("txtAmount"));
   txtAmount.Text = txtAmount.Text.Replace('.', ',');
}
```

or

```
protected void FormView1_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
   var ru = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
   var en = new CultureInfo("en-US")

   decimal d;
   var txtAmount = (TextBox)((FormView)sender).FindControl("txtAmount"));
   if (!Decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, ru, out d)
     && Decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, en, out d)
   {
       // data isn't in Russian format but is in American
       txtAmount.Text = d.ToString(ru);
   }
}
```

Are there any other ideas?

Comment: Do you really want to parse both in the same context? What about things like "£2,000,000.45"?

Comment: @SK-logic: No currency signs by specification. But about both symbols in one input string I need to think more. This is very rare but still possible case. I think my second variant (and Alex's answer) is the most suitable approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try parse to Russian format first and (if unsuccessful) then to US:

```
CultureInfo ru = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU");
CultureInfo us = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

string value = "2000,00";
decimal result;
if (!decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, ru, out result))
{
    if (!decimal.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, us, out result))
    {
        throw new FormatException();
    }
}
```

This should work for both `2000,00` and `2000.00` values.

Also, AFAIK `NumberFormatInfo` class doesn't accept multiple values for separators (e.g. `",."` for `NumberDecimalSeparator` or `CurrencyDecimalSeparator` properties).

Suppose, `String.Replace` is also is not a very good idea because US culture uses comma symbol as group separator (RU uses space).

Comment: Yea, I was thinking about `Decimal.TryParse` too. But keep in mind - I'm inserting the data using `SqlDataSource` so it being parsed not by me in code-behind but by ASP.NET. So I need to prepare the data not to parse

Answer (score 1):

How about using String.Format for currency?

Here is short example:

```
decimal money = 999.99m;
string html = String.Format("Total: {0:C}", money);
```

Information on how to use String.Format + specific culture can be found [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

Comment: My Amount is into a `asp:TextBox` within a `asp:FormView`